# how to cancel LoaderLock MDA using App.exe.config file

Tags: .net, directx, config, loaderlock

I'm not good at English. I'm sorry.
Questions to many capable coders around the world.

- .Net framework 4.7.2
- Visual Studio 2019
- Using Microsoft.directX API

I'm trying to set the app.exe.config file so that the Loaderlock MDA error doesn't appear when someone else starts the program.

in application.exe.config File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="VideoPlayerTest.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
<mdaConfig>  
  <assistants>  
    <loaderLock/>  
  </assistants>  
</mdaConfig>
</configuration>
```

How do I implement the expression syntax to release(loaderlock cancel)

Please help new coding beginners thank you

2021 08 30 at solved by simon Mourier's advice

```xml
<mdaConfig>  
  <assistants>  
    <loaderLock enable="false"/>  
  </assistants>  
</mdaConfig>
```

thank you adivicer

and I have a friend who asked the same question as me.
https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/disable-mda-for-loaderlock.2851033/

Comment: Do you have an error when running outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: Loaderlock errors happen to other people. (from another local to git clone)
 The problem is like the example link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650025/loader-lock-exception-while-playing-audio-using-directx) @SimonMourier

Comment: yes i have an error when running outside of Visual Studio

Comment: Does 'outside' mean that when I run the program on someone else's computer, I get an error?

Comment: You shouldn't see an MDA exception raised if your program is not ran under a debugger such as Visual Studio or WinDBG, unless MDA are explicitly enabled. Read these carefully https://mhogstrom.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/diagnosing-errors-with-managed-debugging-assistants/ and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/diagnosing-errors-with-managed-debugging-assistants#enable-and-disable-mdas